# Reading unicode from sqlite db using python

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode

The data stored in unicode (in database) has to be retrieved and convert into a different form.

The following snippet

```
def convert(content):
    content = content.replace("ஜௌ", "n\[s");
    return content;

mydatabase = "database.db"
connection = sqlite3.connect(mydatabase)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = ''' select unicode_data from table1'''
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor.fetchone():
    print convert(row)
```

yields the following error message in convert method.

> exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

If the database content is **"ஜௌஜௌஜௌ"**, the output should be **"n\[sn\[sn\[s"**

The documentation suggests to use ignore or replace to avoid the error, when creating the unicode string.

when the iteration is changed as follows:

```
for row in cursor.fetchone():
    print convert(unicode(row, errors='replace'))
```

it returns

> exceptions.TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

which informs that row is already a unicode.

Any light on this to make it work is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: try putting using `u"example"` for your unicode strings in your python script. It's irritating, but Python 2 has two types of strings, `unicode` and `str`. Not sure about the technical side, these may be 8-bit (encoded e.g. using UTF-8) and 16-bit strings, for example. Plus, you probably want `\\[`?

Comment: Thanks Anony-Mousse for your useful comment and it worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content = content.replace("ஜௌ", "n\[s");
```

Suggest you mean:

```
content = content.replace(u'ஜௌ', ur'n\[s');
```

or for safety where the encoding of your file is uncertain:

```
content = content.replace(u'\u0B9C\u0BCC', ur'n\[s');
```

The content you have is already Unicode, so you should do Unicode string replacements on it. `"ஜௌ"` without the `u` is a string of bytes that represents those characters in some encoding dependent on your source file charset. (Byte strings work smoothly together with Unicode strings only in the most unambiguous cases, which is for ASCII characters.)

(The `r`-string means not having to worry about including bare backslashes.)